# нажатая кнопка bootstrap вылазит на открытый datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Проблема в том что когда нажал на кнопку на странице и после открыл окно выбора даты datepicker, эта кнопка отрисовывается сверху окна datepicker
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как ее спрятать когда открыт datepicker?

ps кнопки на странице это группа инпутов типа radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К блоку с датой добавьте `z-index` отличный от нуля

Но нужно конечно смотреть css код кнопки и датапикера, возможно нужно наоборот убрать `z-index` у кнопки или добавить `position:relative` у родителя датапикера

Без кода не угадать

Comment: пользовательский css абсолютно пустой, только bootstrap

Comment: Тогда если гадать, то я бы добавил у родительского блока датапикера `position:relative` и `z-index:100` или у самого датапикера добавил `z-index:100`